# Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end ---> Data cannot be read because it isn't in the correct format iOS Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, alamofire

So this is my network request.

//MARK:- Network Request

```
let urlString = Constants.kBaseUrl + Constants.kEventsUrl

Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON, headers: [Constants.kChecksum:Constants.kChecksumValue]) .responseJSON { response in

    guard response.result.isSuccess else {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title:"Error", message:response.result.error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { action in
            self.isFetchingEvents = false;
            self.eventsFetchError = response.result.error
            self.eventsTableView.reloadData()
        })

        let retryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .Default, handler: { action in
            self.downloadEvents()
        })

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(retryAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil);

        return
    }

    let tempInfo = response.result.value![Constants.kData] as! [AnyObject]
```

//MARK:- and my json response from postman

```
 {
  "success": 1,
  "message": "Successful",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "196",
      "title": "Arusha Christmas Fair 2016",
      "body": null,
      "field_events_date_from": "2016-12-24",
      "field_events_date_to": "2016-12-25",
      "field_events_time_from": "2016-10-03 13:56",
      "field_events_time_to": "2016-10-03 21:57",
      "image": "http://clients.view9.com.np/jwaremap/sites/default/files/events/2250x3324-christmas-fair_0.png",
      "image-thumbnail": "http://clients.view9.com.np/jwaremap/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/events/2250x3324-christmas-fair_0.png?itok=U2W8DgA-",
      "image-medium": "http://clients.view9.com.np/jwaremap/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/events/2250x3324-christmas-fair_0.png?itok=ZZlYlC6L",
      "image-large": "http://clients.view9.com.np/jwaremap/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/events/2250x3324-christmas-fair_0.png?itok=-vZhcEag",
      "image-providercategory_threex": "http://clients.view9.com.np/jwaremap/sites/default/files/styles/providercategory-threex/public/events/2250x3324-christmas-fair_0.png?itok=hwpr3WQd",
      "field_events_location": {
        "lat": "-3.416825167067",
        "lon": "36.657226562500"
      },
      "field_events_address": "TGT Grounds",
      "field_events_email": "info@arushafair.com",
      "field_events_contact": null,
      "field_events_website": "www.arushafair.com",
      "field_trip_advisor": null,
      "field_facebook": "https://web.facebook.com/events/681411865357050/",
      "field_twitter": null,
      "field_youtube": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Pvisfxe6CA",
      "field_info": "The ARUSHA COMMUNITY CHRISTMAS FAIR is the most anticipated holiday shopping and family fun event of the year -- hosting over 125 vendors and artisans from across East Africa and 5,000 visitors enjoying local talent, Arusha's best food and drink, lots of activities for the kids, and the chance to take home great prizes in the fantastic raffle and silent auction."
    }
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "superadmin",
    "field_user_phone": "",
    "field_user_address": {
      "lat": "",
      "lon": "",
      "address": ""
    },
    "modified_date": "1475475942"
  },
  "total_items": 1,
  "last_update": "1475475942"
}
```

However, it always enters inside the else block and throws error

**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.})**

While printing the error description, it returns 
**"The data couldn't be read because it is not in the correct format."**

This is my url :

**http://clients.view9.com.np/jwaremap/api/v1/content/events**

And this is the header key required :

**["checksum":"3389dae361af79b04c9c8e7057f60cc6"]**

On validating the json structure with jsonlint.com, it is validating it as a valid json. On using .responseString instead of .responseJSON, I am getting the results.

I don't know where I am missing out

Somebody please tell me where m i missing out..

Comment: Wrong JSON.. please check with http://jsonlint.com by copying your JSON.

Comment: I did.. it is  saying that the json format is valid

Comment: I copied your JSON from ur question & it is invalid.

Comment: please check again

Comment: I have written the url and the header value there. you can even check it in the postman

Comment: I have updated my question.. please check

Comment: your response from server is not in correct format .  Tried but response is not in proper JSON format.  Simply create a NSURLSsession object to get the response. You would find the issue.

Comment: but when i check the json response from postman- which i have mentioned above .,, in jsonlint, it returns valid json

Comment: shall I post my code? Or you can create a NSURLSession for the same

Answer (score 1):

Check your web service response it is not an valid json, That's why you are getting this sort of error.

Try to view your json response here :- http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

There is one missing perenthesis ' } ' in the end of your postman json response.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake.. missed out while writing the question

Comment: let me check then.

Comment: Did you? You can even try checking the response in postman.. I have provided the url and header values there

Comment: use .responseJSON instead of .responseString, as you are getting json from your web api.

Comment: Yea I am using .responseJSON . and it shows the error I have mentioned above